# Use GuidRepresentation.Standard with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, guid, mongodb-.net-driver

I am implementing a custom IBsonSerializer with the official MongoDB driver (C#). I am in the situation where I must serialize and deserialize a Guid.

If I implement the Serialize method as follow, it works:

```
public void Serialize(BsonWriter bsonWriter, Type nominalType, object value, IBsonSerializationOptions options)
{
    BsonBinaryData data = new BsonBinaryData(value, GuidRepresentation.CSharpLegacy);
    bsonWriter.WriteBinaryData(data);
}
```

However I don't want the Guid representation to be CSharpLegacy, I want to use the standard representation. But if I change the Guid representation in that code, I get the following error:

> MongoDB.Bson.BsonSerializationException: The GuidRepresentation for the writer is CSharpLegacy, which requires the subType argument to be UuidLegacy, not UuidStandard.

How do I serialize a Guid value using the standard representation?

Comment: What are the runtime types for nominalType and value parameters?

Comment: nominalType is Guid in this case and value is the Guid (in reality, it is an object represented by a guid, and I serialize value.InternalGuid)

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are changing when you say "if I change the Guid representation in that code" - can you include the actual code which gives you the error you quoted?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Old question but in case someone finds it on google like I did...

Do this once:

```
BsonDefaults.GuidRepresentation = GuidRepresentation.Standard;
```

For example, in a Web Application/Web API, your **Global.asax.cs** file is best place to add it once

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
   protected void Application_Start()
   {
      BsonDefaults.GuidRepresentation = GuidRepresentation.Standard;

      //Other code...below

   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to modify the global setting `BsonDefaults.GuidRepresentation` (and you shouldn't, because modifying globals is a bad pattern), you can specify the setting when you create your collection:

```
IMongoDatabase db = ???;
string collectionName = ???;
var collectionSettings = new MongoCollectionSettings {
  GuidRepresentation = GuidRepresentation.Standard
};
var collection = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(collectionName, collectionSettings);
```

Then any GUIDs written to the collection will be in the standard format.

Note that when you read records from the database, you will get a `System.FormatException` if the GUID format in the database is different from the format in your collection settings.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like what's happening is when you are not explicitly passing the GuidRepresentation to `BsonBinaryData` constructor, it defaults to passing `GuidRepresentation.Unspecified` and that ultimately maps to `GuidRepresentation.Legacy` (see [this line](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/v1.10.1/MongoDB.Bson/ObjectModel/BsonBinaryData.cs#L74) in the source)

So you need to explicitly pass the guidRepresentation as a third argument to BsonBinaryData set to `GuidRepresentation.Standard`.

*edit:* As was later pointed out, you can set `BsonDefaults.GuidRepresentation = GuidRepresentation.Standard` if that's what you always want to use.

Comment: presumably this was done so as not to break any "existing" code using Legacy representation?

Comment: Hm, no, `new BsonBinaryData(guid.ToByteArray(), BsonBinarySubType.UuidStandard, GuidRepresentation.Standard)` gives the same error.

Comment: That would be because your _binaryWriterSettings.GuidRepresentation is set to CSharpLegacy.

Comment: Yes I got that, but how do I change my writer to not have this GuidRepresentation? If I try to change it from Serialize, it throws an exception, says it's frozen. Looks like I have no control on this writer, or do I?

Comment: you are passing bsonWriter to Serialize.  Change it where you call its constructor.

Comment: The referenced source file has changed to https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/445ce4fa19da1de050389907369ea649d51f88a5/src/MongoDB.Bson/ObjectModel/BsonBinaryData.cs

Comment: Thanks @GaTechThomas I changed the link to point to the version that was active at that time (this way the link won't become obsolete again).